# SQL Group by: how to get % of records over a certain score

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a SQL table similar to the below. How do I do a SQL Group By where I can get the percentage of calls rated 9 or above per step?

So basically I want to group by StepID and next to it I want to show the % of calls that has its rating over 9.

```
CallID  StepID  Rating
1         1       8
1         2       6
1         3       9
2         1       10
2         2       10
2         3       5
3         1       7
3         2       5
3         3       8
```

In this case, next to StepID = 1, would display 33% (1 out of 3 calls for stepID 1 is over 9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
 StepID, 
 cast(sum(case when Rating > 9 then 100.0 else 0 end)
 /count(*) as decimal(5,2)) pct
from yourtable
group by StepID
```